# Convert DataRow to TableRow

Tags: c#, asp.net

Simple enough. Cant find a simple solution. Not sure if their is a simple solution? :/

I have a dataTable. I essentially want to achieve this...

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dt);

TableRow tr = new TableRow();
tr = dt.Rows[0];
```

but i cant convert from DataRow to a TableRow!

Help!

Alex

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Im trying to get the data from a DataRow object, and put it into a TableRow Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your goal is to show on the UI the data that are within a dataTable(or any other datasource) why don't you use a repeater?

anyway you can't just convert the DataTableRow to TableRow but you have to do it yourself.
have a look at the below code

```
private void GenerateTable()

    {

        DataTable dt = CreateDataTable();

        Table table = new Table();

        TableRow row = null;



        //Add the Headers

        row = new TableRow();

        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)

        {

            TableHeaderCell headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();

            headerCell.Text = dt.Columns[j].ColumnName;

            row.Cells.Add(headerCell);

        }

        table.Rows.Add(row);



        //Add the Column values

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)

        {

            row = new TableRow();

            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)

            {

                TableCell cell = new TableCell();

                cell.Text = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();

                row.Cells.Add(cell);

            }

            // Add the TableRow to the Table

            table.Rows.Add(row);

        }

        // Add the the Table in the Form

        form1.Controls.Add(table);

    }
```

source:

http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/24/fill-asp.net-table-with-data-from-datatable.aspx

Comment: I was trying to do it the lazy way but looks like ill have to do it this way. cheers bro x

Comment: if you use a repeater instead you can juts DataBind your datatable to the repeater itself with no effort.The repeater will be rendered as a classic HTML table.

Comment: row = new TableRow();  <--- TableRow requires constructor:
 Assembly: TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=2.4.0.0,

TableRow(Table table, string[] items)

:-(

Answer (score 4):

A TableRow is a UI element, it is represents a row within a Table control). The DataRow is a data element, it represents a row of data within a DataTable. You can't convert between the two like this because they are simply different beasts.

If you're looking to work with the UI then you should bind the Table control to the DataTable. Then you can pull the individual TableRow objects.

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

TableRow tr = new TableRow();

```
    tr .Cells(0).Text = dt.Rows[0][0];
```

because TabeRow have so many cell, you must have to specified cell. there is no method to add whole datarow in to TableRow both are Different.

Comment: menace for each row you have add separate, you must have to use loop or something..